# Re-arranging a two-way table

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to make sense of some data with a two-way table (using `gmodels` - but I am open to doing this in a tidyverse way too) and I can't work out how to control the order of the columns and the rows.

I would like `TRUE` to be the first column, and `TRUE` to be the first row. Here's some code I have.

```
library(gmodels)
# some dummy data 
df <- tibble(green = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
             pink = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

CrossTable(
  df$pink,
  df$green, 
  prop.r = FALSE,
  prop.t = FALSE,
  prop.c = FALSE,
  prop.chisq = FALSE,
  chisq = FALSE
)
```

The above code produces output in a different column/row order than I want:

```
             | df$green 
     df$pink |     FALSE |      TRUE | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
       FALSE |         2 |         2 |         4 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        TRUE |         4 |         1 |         5 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |         6 |         3 |         9 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

But what I want to see is something like this (which I've done by hand):

```
             | df$green 
     df$pink |     TRUE  |     FALSE | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        TRUE |         1 |         4 |         5 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
       FALSE |         2 |         2 |         4 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |         3 |         6 |         9 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ordered factors. try this

```
library(gmodels)
library(dplyr)
# some dummy data 
df <- tibble(green = factor(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), levels = c('TRUE', 'FALSE')), 
             pink = factor(c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), levels = c('TRUE', 'FALSE')))

CrossTable(
  df$pink,
  df$green, 
  prop.r = FALSE,
  prop.t = FALSE,
  prop.c = FALSE,
  prop.chisq = FALSE,
  chisq = FALSE
)
```

and you will get this:

```
             | df$green 
     df$pink |      TRUE |     FALSE | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        TRUE |         1 |         4 |         5 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
       FALSE |         2 |         2 |         4 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |         3 |         6 |         9 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with base function table and convert it to data.frame and change the order of column

Here is the code

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))[,c("TRUE","FALSE")]
```